# Cant use variable from included PHP File

Tags: php, apache, include

I don't know how to search for it, so I'm asking you here.

Situation is the following:

Got a vServer with root. Apache, PHP5, MySQL installed and running.

Now I have an `index.php` where I want to `include 'config.php';`. Simple thing!

In the `config.php` I have a variable like `$url = 'http://xxxxxxx';`, but I cannot access it in the `index.php`. There's just an empty Array, when I `print_r(parse_url($url));` it.

The curious thing is, when I'm connected with ssh to the server and run `php index.php`, the output is the whole array as expected.

Do you have any idea?!

Comment: Try switching from `include` to require. The only thing I can think of that might be causing that is your included file not being found.

Comment: Just tried it, it also doesnt work. When I want to include a not existing file, my site doesnt load anything (maybe need to fix the error handling..)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; when you used `require` did you get a message saying it couldn't find the file (and so didn't work)? Or did it try to run, but still displayed an empty array for `$url`?

Comment: I think I destroyed my php.ini (something with `display_errors`), so the whole site isnt loading, when I `require` a not existing file. Need to fix it later when I'm at home.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to include your config.php with absolute path, eg. include('/var/www/config.php');

Comment: Try var_dump($url) and see if its recognized.

Answer (score 0):

The best strategy for a config file would be having it written in the following format:

```
<?php
    return array(
        'url' => 'http://xxxxxxx',
        ...
    );
```

Then in your `index.php` you can do `$config = require('wherever/it/is/config.php')` and access your parameters like `$config['url']`. Otherwise you would probably have to use globals which is almost never a good practice.

Comment: This is how I want to do it later, but for now I just need to access any variable, before extending my config. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, then just make sure you are using the global version of the `$url` variable, 'cause if, for example, you're doing your include, then are trying to use the variable from within a function without declaring it as global, it will be a completely different variable. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for details. Sorry, if I'm stating the obvious, but without the complete listing all I can do is assume. :)

Comment: Is it something similar to the following?

`index.php`:

`<?php
        include 'config.php';

        echo $url."\n";
    ?>`

and `config.php`:

    `<?php
        $url = 'http://somethingcool.com/';
    ?>`

It's always a good idea to provide a kind of listing if you want to receive some meaningful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Damn, I'm so stupid.

I had something like:

**config.php**

```
foreach {
    if(true){
        something;
        return false;
    }
}
$url = ...;
```

I just wanted to stop the `foreach` if it was successful. Maybe worked too good..

But I don't understand, why it hadn't any errors when `php`ing it in the terminal..

Thank you guys!